# Puppeteer - image download with authentication query string in image URL

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, request, puppeteer, query-string

I am trying to save images that are stored in an account web-space. Access the private space with the credentials and access the image link is all fine with `Puppeteer`.
But the `src` attribute of the image give a URL with additional authentication query strings. The url works fine directly in the browser, or with the `page.evaluate()` command. Both open a filechooser to download the image. But with `page.goto()`, error say I cannot navigate invalid URL.
I tried all downloading methods i found, but nothing works!
How can I download the images with `Puppeteer` with this kind of URLs?

The URL giving access to the image without all the authentification in the account, i tried to isolate the problem and only download the image from the URL above. But unfortunately nothing works.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({executablePath: '/usr/bin/brave-browser', headless: false});
const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://s3.amazonaws.com/spypoint-production-account-failover/5c9f7dc7267fc300f968bb01/60632085b8683500145706d1/20230213/PICT1853_202302131500FHth3.jpg?X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-Date=20230401T094532Z&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIATVANQEDJ5KPEZXK2%2F20230401%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=e9be25f01b577c1116b1c5ee00e0a1c1386b716cc7fe0ea19cd4aad77d61684d');
  await page.waitForNavigation();
  await screenshot();
})();
```

(I even ask `ChatGPT`, but it doesn't help me...!)
Thanks a lot.

Comment: `await page.waitForNavigation();` looks out of place here. `goto` already waits for navigation. I'd remove that. If `evaluate` works, why not use that? Why do you need to use Puppeteer at all for that matter?

Comment: @ggorlen Thanks for question. It was the problem of many people, so I try it. And had the error : `Error: net::ERR_ABORTED`. I thought it could help. But now I had the answer, all is fine! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url you have doesn't require anything so directly download the image(s), you don't need puppeteer for such urls.

```js
let fs = require('fs');
let http = require('https');

let browser;
(async () => {

    let url = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/spypoint-production-account-failover/5c9f7dc7267fc300f968bb01/60632085b8683500145706d1/20230213/PICT1853_202302131500FHth3.jpg?X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-Date=20230401T094532Z&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIATVANQEDJ5KPEZXK2%2F20230401%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=e9be25f01b577c1116b1c5ee00e0a1c1386b716cc7fe0ea19cd4aad77d61684d';

    function download(url, path) {
        http.get(url, (res) => {
            res.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path, {flags: "w+"}));
        });
    }

    download(url, './test.jpg');


})().catch(err => console.error(err)). finally(() => browser ?. close());
```